# How to propagate a .attr() change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of html elements that have an 'data-'attribute that specify what is the next element to be viewed (This is a Video List).

[data-PosInListVid='nextListVid'] -> Indicates that this element is next

[data-PosInListVid='ListVid'] -> Indicates that this element is in the middle of the list

[data-PosInListVid='lastListVid'] -> indicates that the list stops here

When the video endes, I call an .Ajax() and on success It calls some functions. One of those functions is ment to remove the attribute data-PosInListVid='nextListVid' from previous Video, and insert it in the next element of List. I do it like this:

```
function changeVidList($newVid) {

    //In the List, Videos have positions so...
    var newPosition = $newVid.attr("data-ListVidOrder"); //get the position of the former "nextVideo" 

    var nextPosition = Number(newPosition) + 1; //specify what is the position of the Next video.

    var $videoAfterNewVideo = $("[data-ListVidOrder='" + nextPosition + "']"); //Get the element with next position

    $newVid.attr("data-PosInListVid", "ListVid"); // edit attribute data-PosInListVid from nextListVid to ListVid 

    $videoAfterNewVideo.attr("data-PosInListVid", "nextListVid"); // edit attribute data-PosInListVid from ListVid to nextListVid making it next in line. 

    return false;

};
```

Problem: When It tries get the new element with:

```
var newVidObjDiv = $("[data-PosInListVid='nextListVid']");
```

newVidObjDiv is undefined, despite the element having it specified.

I guess this is a problem with propagating the .attr() change. Normaly I use .on() to propagate, but dont know how to inform DOM that there was a change via .attr(), and make it ready to be selected with jquery.

Can Anyone help me in here? Thanks you so much

EDIT:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {

    var newVid;
    newVid = $("[data-PosInListVid='nextListVid']").attr("data-nextListVidYTID");

    VidID = newVid;

    var newVidObjDiv = $("[data-PosInListVid='nextListVid']"); //<--- Here is where I call newVidObjDiv

    ajaxGetVid(newVidObjDiv);


    return false;

    }

}

function ajaxGetVid($link) {
$.ajax({
    type: options.type,
    url: options.url,
    data: options.data,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data)

        $(options.target).html(data);

        onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();


        changeVidList($link); // <---- .attr() changing.
    }
});
```

The flow is ment to be:

Video ON

Video ENDS

AJAX CALL

VIDEO STARTS

CHANGE DOM

VIDEO ENDS

AJAX CALL WITH NEW DOM

VIDEO DOES NOT START

Its 4:20 a.m I may be doing a stupid mistake...

Comment: No, `attr` changes are made synchronously: https://jsfiddle.net/hqmdgbL8/
When do you make this `var newVidObjDiv = $("[data-PosInListVid='nextListVid']");` call? (and if `$` is the shorthand for `jQuery`, then `$()` never returns undefined.